# How to pass a * character as a command-line argument on Windows 10 command prompt?

Tags: cmd, windows-10, command-line-arguments, wildcard

I have written a C program which takes many command line arguments, among which last one can be a `*`. I have compiled it using mingw-w64 compiler and I am using Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508] command prompt.

How to pass a `*` character as a command-line argument? I have tried many escape sequences like `*`, `^*`, `^^*`, `!*`, `\*`, `/*`, `"*"`, and `'*'`, but none of them is working. Only `'*'` is being passed as it is but I want to pass only `*` character without any inverted commas. Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit: You can assume MRE to be

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (*argv[1] == '*')
        printf("A asterisk is passed.\n");
}
```

Comment: Please provide an MRE (Minimal Reproducable Example). A simple program to print the values in argv[].

Comment: Do you need globbing (wildcard expansion) at all or are you OK with turning it off altogether? The latter can be done by setting a global `_CRT_glob` to `0`. Note that this expansion is performed by MinGW for Unix compatibility; Windows itself doesn't expand wildcards (and neither does `cmd`, of course). If you need globbing but want to escape this specific instance, things get trickier.

Comment: @JeroenMostert How to set `_CRT_glob` variable to `0`?

Comment: From what I've read putting in an `extern int _CRT_glob = 0;` declaration in your program somewhere suffices.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks a lot! This worked.
But what if I want to pass two `*` as command-line argument, one `*` should be globed and another one should be not? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes -- turn off implicit globbing and call [`glob()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) yourself (I can't check myself but I believe current versions of MinGW come with `glob.h`). Of course you can also use specific functions like [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) if you want the DOS/Windows logic rather than Unix wildcards.